# Add a value for Testbed provider in one of hthe tests

Tags: angular, testing

How can you change a value for a Testbed provider in a test without having to redefine the entire TestBed?

```
describe('a test', () => {
  let router: Router;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;
  let location: Location;

  // want to be able to update this object
  let initialQueryParams: {} = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {
            path: '',
            component: DummyComponent,
          }
        ])
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: ActivatedRoute,
        useValue: {
          snapshot: {
          queryParams: initialQueryParams
        }
      }
    }],

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
  });

  it('should...', () => {
    functionWhichHasRouterNavigate();

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/');
  });

  it('should do something else...', () => {
   initialQueryParams = { baz: 'qux' };
  
    functionWhichHasRouterNavigate();

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/?baz=qux');
  });

});
```

I've tried wrapping everything in the beforeEach block into a function `setup = () => { ... }`, but that made the test flakey. The values leaked into one another somehow

Comment: What about using a mock/spy class?

Comment: Could be. I just would like to know if the route/url changes and will get the query params. What should I be mocking/spy-ing? Spyon will require a method, and I'm not sure which method I could spy on.

Comment: Couldnt creating a reference work? If you did a let mockRouter; and then in the beforeEach, do a mockRouter = {snapshot: queryParams: {foo: 'bar'}}; and in your provider {provide: activatedRoute, useValue: mockRouter};
Then in your test inside the it block, all you would have to do is mockRouter = {...mockRouter, snapshot: { queryParams: {foo: 'clazz'} }} before you   invoke your test method

Comment: No, somehow those mocked query params are not used in the function. Perhaps because of an TestBed.inject method that's used. I don't have it in this description,I'll add it.